# package-lock.json is not generated when using `npm i` (npm v6.3.0, node v8.9.2)

Tags: node.js, npm

For some of my projects, I don't know why, the `package-lock.json` file is not being generated by `npm i`, nor `npm install --package-lock` nor anything I could try...

I also tried to `rm -rf node-modules && npm i`, same result.

I read all the related questions I could find here or on the internet, but none of them could help in my current context:

- I do have a `.npmrc`, but it only contains this single character: '8' (requiring version 8 of node)
- `npm -v` returns `6.3.0`
- `node -v` returns `v8.9.2`

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm config list`

The global setting `package-lock=false` indicates that package lock will not get generated.

Try `npm config set package-lock true` OR `npm install --package-lock`

Hope this helps